# iOS identify completion of multiple asynchronous calls

Tags: ios, swift, asynchronous

I have an object that is parsed from a JSON API-response. This object has a link to a thumbnail picture. I have an array with multiple objects that i want to download the thumbnail picture for. So i have a loop start starts an async call for each thumbnail link.

So i have this object in a ViewController, i start the download of all images, How can i detect when all calls are completed?

This is my code:

```
public class NewsListItem: NSObject {
    public var entries: [NewsListEntry]? = []

    public func downloadThumbnails() {
        for itm in entries! {
            if(itm.thumbnail != "") {
                itm.downloadThumbnail()
            }
        }
    }
}


public class NewsListEntry: NSObject {
    public var thumbnail: String = ""
    public var thumbnailImage: UIImage = UIImage()


    public func downloadThumbnail() {
            GetImageHandeler().getImage(self.thumbnail, completionHandler: { (responseObject, error) in
                    self.thumbnailImage = responseObject!
            })
    }
}
```

Comment: recommend you to use https://github.com/BoltsFramework/Bolts-iOS

Answer (score 3):

You can use dispatch_groups for this. In obj C it would look like something like this:

```
dispatch_group_t serviceGroup = dispatch_group_create();

for (itm in entries){
   dispatch_group_enter(serviceGroup);
   [ImageHandler getImage:^(ConfigResponse *results, NSError* error){
     // Do something with the error or results
     dispatch_group_leave(serviceGroup);
   }];
}

dispatch_group_notify(serviceGroup,dispatch_get_main_queue(),^{
   // Do your stuff, everything has finished
});
```

You can find a more detailed example [here](http://commandshift.co.uk/blog/2014/03/19/using-dispatch-groups-to-wait-for-multiple-web-services/)